# Why is this the first step of differentiating [a^u(x)]

Tags: derivatives, differential

Following this [enter link description here](https://www.derivative-calculator.net/#expr=5%5E%28xcosx%29&showsteps=1), where we're performing the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}5^{x\cos(x)},$$

The first step of the differentiation is:

$[a^u(x)]'$ = $ \ln(a) \,a^u(x)\, u'(x).$

I’m quite confused by the intuition. Where did the $\ln$ come from? Why do we need to multiply by $a^u(x)?$

Would appreciate a step by step breakdown of why this is the first step. Is this just another differentiation rule to remember (like chain rule, product rule) that I should instinctively know when performing differentiation, or is there some manipulation that lead to the equation above? This is a new topic for me, apologies.

Comment: All rules are a consequence of the definition, but since you mentioned chain rule and product rule, then yes, it is a consequence of those too and that $(e^x)'=e^x$. $a^{u(x)}=e^{u(x)\cdot \ln(a)}$. Applying the chain rule $(a^{u(x)})'=e^{u(x)\cdot\ln(a)}\cdot(u(x)\cdot\ln(a))'=a^{u(x)}\cdot(u(x)\cdot\ln(a))'$. Now apply the product rule to $(u(x)\cdot\ln(a))'=\ln(a)u'(x)$.

Comment: @JamesSoh Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that

$$a^{u(x)}=e^{u(x)\cdot \log a}$$

and then

$$(a^{u(x)})'=(e^{u(x)\cdot \log a})'=e^{u(x)\cdot \log a}\cdot (u(x) \cdot \log a)'=a^{u(x)}\cdot u'(x) \cdot \log a$$

Comment: To the proposer: The second "$=$" in the last line  is by the chain rule  $(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ with $f(y)=e^y =(e^y)' $ and $g(x)=u(x)\ln x.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for the further clarification of that point.

Comment: I thought the proposer might not see it.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet In any case "*repetita iuvant*". Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

That rule is obtained using *logarithmic differentiation*. Taking logs essentially converts an exponentiation into a multiplication, allowing you to use the already-familiar product rule. You can use it to derive the generalized power rule for derivatives:
$$\left(f^g\right)' = gf^{g-1}\cdot f' + f^g\log f\cdot g'$$
where $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ and $'$ denotes differentiation with respect to $x$.

The beauty of this rule is that if $g$ is constant then $g'$ vanishes and you recover the power rule, and if $f$ is constant then $f'$ vanishes and you recover the exponential rule. That makes it really easy to memorize.

To derive it using logarithmic differentiation, write

$$y=f^g$$
We're looking for $y'$. Taking logs:
$$\log y = g\log f\tag{power property for logs}$$
$$\tfrac{y'}{y}=g\cdot\tfrac{f'}{f}+\log f\cdot g'\tag{prod rule, deriv of log}$$
$$y'=gy\cdot\tfrac{f'}{f}+y\log f\cdot g'\tag{mult by $y$}$$
$$y'=g(f^g)(f)^{-1}\cdot f' +(f^g)\log f\cdot g'\tag{defn of $y$}$$
$$y'=\boxed{gf^{g-1}\cdot f' + f^g\log f\cdot g'}\tag{combine exponents}$$